# Continuously monitor connection of C# socket instance even if Ethernet cable is removed

Tags: c#, sockets

Currently I am working on a project where I am using 4 TCP/IP Connections using different C# socket instance. but my project requirement is to continuously monitor these connection whether on or off. I have used poll method but it is only shows last status of connectivity but if Ethernet cable supposed to be removed then it is still shows last status. I need to check all time proper connection is their or not is all cases. please help me to solve this issue

my poll method function

```
public static bool IsSocketConnected(Socket s)
        {
            try
            {
                if (s != null)
                    return !((s.Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectRead) &&      (s.Available == 0)) || !s.Connected);
                else
                    return false;
            }
            catch(Exception es)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: well, I would probably start with not swallowing the exceptions by returning false, and also handling the cases where `s == null`, again rather than returning false.

Comment: You can't tell with Ethernet when a cable is pulled unless you test an open socket.  You may want to test for traffic on a port where multicast traffic is being sent or use ping to another PC to verify connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Connections only exist on the TCP level - the network interface just sends messages. TCP is pretty smart, and can assure that each message arrives in the order it was sent.

However it cannot detect if the other side has become unreachable without sending a message, such as a periodic keep-alive request.